# How to convert array to string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Hi i am using CakePHP version 2.x

I am print my array using

```
pr($this->request->params['named']);

//Output
Array
(
    [street_name] => Bhubaneswar
    [house_number] => 1247
    [phone] => xxxxxxxx
    [zip] => xxxxx
)
```

In above array i want to view looks like

```
/street_name:Bhubaneswar/house_number:1247/phone:xxxxxxxx/zip:xxxxx
```

How to convert above array in string format?

Comment: Hi @Rikesh  i tried `echo $string = implode("/",$this->request->params['named']);` but i am not getting the perfect result.

Comment: Thanks for giving minus(-) vote. I got my answer. thanks Miraage and Sal00m

Comment: You probably got the - for not showing any research effort, and not making it clear what you want to do with that string, and why you can't use CakePHP tools like `Router::url()`. So maybe try to write better questions instead of complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$strResult = "";
foreach ($this->request->params['named'] as $key=>$value){
    $strResult .= "/{$key}:{$value}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most easy and speedy solution.

```
$result = '';
foreach ($this->request->params['name'] as $k => $v) {
    $result .= sprintf('/%s:%s', $k, $v);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a one-liner:

```
echo '/' . str_replace('=', ':', http_build_query($array, '', '/'));
```

Would output:

```
/street_name:Bhubaneswar/house_number:1247/phone:xxx/zip:xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value){
    echo "/". $key . ":" . $value;
}
```

Comment: `+` is not tthe operator to concat strings in PHP, replace with `.`

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
$ar = array('street_name' => 'Bhubaneswar',
    'house_number' => 1247,
    'phone' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'zip' => 'xxxxx');
echo convert($ar);

function convert($ar)
{
    $str = '';
    foreach($ar as $i=>$k)
    {
        $str .= '/'.$i.':'.$k;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

### Output

```
/street_name:Bhubaneswar/house_number:1247/phone:xxxxxxxx/zip:xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function implode_with_keys($glue, $separator, $pieces)
{
    $string = '';
    foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
        $string .= $glue . $key . $separator . $value;
    }
    return $string;
}
```

In your case you'd use it like this:

```
implode_with_keys('/', ':', $this->request->params['named']);
```

This will return the desired string `/street_name:Bhubaneswar/house_number:1247/phone:xxxxxxxx/zip:xxxxx`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'street_name' => 'Bhubaneswar',
    'house_number' => '1247',
    'phone' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'zip' => 'xxxxx',
);

while (current($array)) {

        echo '/'.key($array).':'.$array[key($array)];

    next($array);
}
?>
```

this will return

```
/street_name:Bhubaneswar/house_number:1247/phone:xxxxxxxx/zip:xxxxx
```